# Signed XML with .cer

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to sign an XML document to send to a supplier by a Web Service, but the supplier told me that the data DigestValue and SignatureValue are erroneous, they sent me as depart this data and are different than me puts me, comparing my xml and theirs are the only different data. I put the data returned by me and Supplier

**Supplier**

`<DigestValue>E3wGWNsdBY7ovcY0MRbJu6qPFwo=</DigestValue>SignatureValue>YtBox2b4o+/9nwYr7ULpFJ70gXDP+jSfIjFTAkz85N3ETP1EE+SVCxtlphQl6LfgikG7PsrRo2sW77vL0QSWefNAkDQGuHEd70gyjTMdjVj7URK5u7BnWX4aHoqGYbyQEg2OxhPXXQB6ERJIYckKviuZXitY8Wrb/yQ1/CuL/Ck=</SignatureValue>`

**My Data**

`<DigestValue>iTDhLAQ6s9cdckT206Mtgm0lXgM=</DigestValue>SignatureValue>dkXswnM7hQKwUN+h5WmwReTpFmoWnqViNDMYEu15um6CNeBow3eBasWSEYBbabhZ1nvBAaUmDd5z3Jn931dkdLKzWjX6N75I0sbIF4Fe2cYr/XJi9tojGoCjQL0waI67p006VwPjvq3kiy34cUqVdJmbBdRPXYCD+VHGjTT3hoc=</SignatureValue>`

**The xml that tries to sign it:**

`<Cancelacion Fecha="2014-02-18T11:44:17" RfcEmisor="AAA010101AAA"><Folios><UUID>50bfe0b5-461e-4356-b447-3b4ce02c1377</UUID></Folios></Cancelacion>`

**This is the code that i use to sign the XML**

```
public static void SignXmlFile(string FileName, string SignedFileName, RSA Key, string Certificate)
        {
            // Create a new XML document.
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            // Format the document to ignore white spaces.
            //doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;//false;

            // Load the passed XML file using it's name.
            doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(FileName));

            // Create a SignedXml object.
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

            // Create a reference to be signed.
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = "";

            // Add the key to the SignedXml document. 
            signedXml.SigningKey = Key;
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

            // Create a reference to be signed.
            //Reference reference = new Reference();
            //reference.Uri = "";

            // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            //Transform transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform(false);
            reference.AddTransform(env);
            //reference.AddTransform(transform);

            // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            // Create a new KeyInfo object.
           // KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

            // Load the X509 certificate.
            X509Certificate MSCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Certificate);
            //X509Certificate2
            string resultsTrue = string.Empty;
            resultsTrue = MSCert.ToString(true);

            //X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateBySubject("C:\\CFDV20\\CERTS\\CICE\\CIC910530TC8_1201051226S.p12");
            X509IssuerSerial xserial;

            xserial.IssuerName = MSCert.Issuer.ToString();
            xserial.SerialNumber = MSCert.GetSerialNumberString();

            // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
            // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
           // keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(MSCert));

            KeyInfoX509Data keyData = new KeyInfoX509Data(MSCert);
            X509IssuerSerial x509Serial;
            x509Serial.IssuerName = MSCert.Issuer.ToString();
            x509Serial.SerialNumber = MSCert.GetSerialNumberString();

            //keyData.AddCertificate(MSCert);

            keyData.AddIssuerSerial(x509Serial.IssuerName.ToString(), x509Serial.SerialNumber.ToString());
           // keyData.AddSubjectName(x509Serial.IssuerName);
            //keyData.AddSubjectName(MSCert.Subject.ToString());
            keyInfo.AddClause(keyData);

            //keyData.AddIssuerSerial(x509Serial.IssuerName, x509Serial.SerialNumber);
            //keyInfo.AddClause(keyData);

            // Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

            // Compute the signature.
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

            // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
            // it to an XmlElement object.
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

            // Append the element to the XML document.
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

            if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
            {
                doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
            }
            // Save the signed XML document to a file specified
            // using the passed string.
            XmlTextWriter xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(SignedFileName, new UTF8Encoding(false));
            doc.WriteTo(xmltw);
            xmltw.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please be more specfic in your question? What are you needing help with?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I want to get the same result that the supplier, for the data DigestValue and signature value, thanks